# Adding the split according to the specific rowname in a circular heatmap using R

Tags: r, heatmap, circular-dependency

I am a newer in R. I would like to create a circular heatmap and set some split according to https://jokergoo.github.io/2020/05/21/make-circular-heatmaps/, which says :

If the value for split argument is a factor, the order of the factor levels controls the order of heatmaps. If split is a simple vector, the order of heatmaps is unique(split).

```
# note since circos.clear() was called in the previous plot,
# now the layout starts from theta = 0 (the first sector is 'e')
circos.heatmap(mat1, split = factor(split, levels = c("e", "d", "c", "b", "a")), 
    col = col_fun1, show.sector.labels = TRUE)
```

[refered result plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnEZz.png)

### my data was like this:

[esters.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etBF2.png)

### This is my code

```
library(circlize)
library(ComplexHeatmap)
library(dendextend)

mat1=read.csv("esters.csv")
row.names(mat1)<-mat1[,1]#
mat2<-mat1[,-1]##remove the first column
mat3<-mat1[-1,]##remove the first row
#Draw circoheatmap

col_fun1 = colorRamp2(c(0, 0.00001, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.01,0.1, 0.4, 0.8), c("#FAFAFA", "#EAF7E7", "#E0F3DC", "#D7F0D1", "#CDEBC6", "#D5E4FD", "#8CACE3", "#5E7192"))##
circos.par(start.degree = 90, gap.degree = 10, gap.after = c(10))##

mat1 = mat1[sample(165, 165), ] # randomly permute rows
split = sample(letters[1:5], 165, replace = TRUE)
splits = factor(split, levels = letters[1:5])

circos.heatmap(mat2, col = col_fun1, split = splits, 
    dend.track.height = 0.15,
    dend.side = "inside", 
    rownames.side = "outside",
    dend.callback = function(dend, m, si) {
        color_branches(dend, k = 4, col = 1:4)
    }
)

#By default, the numeric matrix is clustered on rows.
#Used to draw legend


lgd = Legend(title = "Relative abundance", col_fun = col_fun1)
grid.draw(lgd)


circos.clear()
```

[image: my present result plot]

### I want to add the split according to the specific row name, like "ester40", "ester80", "ester128". For example, the first split or sector contained 40 rows named "ester1, ester2, ester3, ester4,...to  ester40" and all columns from "H6d_T" to "M10d_P".

[image: wanted result plot]

I tried my best to understand it, but it still did not work.
Did anyone could tell me what should I type in

```
split = ???
```

Comment: It seems like split should be mat1$Name, `split=mat1$Name`?

Comment: thanks, I tried, it still did not work.

Comment: When you're plotting, you have an x and y; x may be one of the '_T', and y may be one of the '_P', and those two will be your x/y, that will be split by $Name. So, as I don't know esters, but you do, what are your x/y? I ask because you've jumped, via your mat1 and mat2 assignments to the split, without saying split what (x,y). ? So it seems you first want a two column matrix, that will be indexed by $Name in the split part of the function.

Comment: Sorry for my terrible description.  `mat2<-mat1[,-1]` was done to remove the first column from mat1 for acquiring a pure numeric matrix, not for the split.

Comment: I have rewritten my above question description, could you please help me again?

Answer (score 0):

In my code I solved in this way.
I simply created a factor variable, so to make a simplified example with your code... let's say that "ester1", "ester2", "ester3" are the "group1", while "ester4", "ester5", "ester6" are the "group2".
And let's say that the output of

```
rownames(mat1)
```

returns

```
"ester1", "ester2", "ester3", "ester4", "ester5", "ester6"
```

First you need to create a list like this

```
levels <- c("group1","group1","group1","group2","group2","group2")
```

so that there is correspondence between each ester position in the `rownames` and its group in the `levels` vector.

Then simply

`split=factor(levels)`

now you can use this  `split` variable inside the `circos.heatmap` function.